# ¿Como Centrar una imagen de icono dentro de otra imagen?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

tengo un icono de formato imagen (.png) el cual quiero centrarla en una imagen como tal, pero no consigo centrarla, la imagen del icono la añadí dentro de un **y posteriormente está la imagen de fondo, pero no he lidiado con la posición exacta en el centro.
anexo el codigo html y posteriormente el css...

ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO HTML donde está primero el icono de la imagen y el segundo la imagen del fondo

```
  <div><img src="http://www.legacycitychurch.com/media/cover_art/Play%20Button%20Overlay/playbutton.png" style="
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 50%;  
    position: absolute;>">
</div>
<img src="https://process.filestackapi.com/AhTgLagciQByzXpFGRI0Az/resize=width:250,height:200,fit:scale/http://areametropolitana.softwareestrategico.com/PublishingImages/Paginas/Forms/AllItems/Nairo.jpeg" class="img-size" alt="undefined">
```

lo que quisiera es saber que formas hay para centrar esa imagen dentro de una imagen...
[image: la imagen del recuadro donde vá el icono dentro de la imagen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<img src="https://process.filestackapi.com/AhTgLagciQByzXpFGRI0Az/resize=width:250,height:200,fit:scale/http://areametropolitana.softwareestrategico.com/PublishingImages/Paginas/Forms/AllItems/Nairo.jpeg" width="268" hspace="16" height="268" vspace="16" />
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">
<img border="0"  src="http://www.legacycitychurch.com/media/cover_art/Play%20Button%20Overlay/playbutton.png" width="300" height="300"/></div></div>
```

esta es otra forma si le quieres colocar la imagen del reproductor mas pequeña

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<img src="https://process.filestackapi.com/AhTgLagciQByzXpFGRI0Az/resize=width:250,height:200,fit:scale/http://areametropolitana.softwareestrategico.com/PublishingImages/Paginas/Forms/AllItems/Nairo.jpeg" width="268"/>
<div style="position:absolute; top:30%; left:10%;">

<img border="0"  src="http://www.legacycitychurch.com/media/cover_art/Play%20Button%20Overlay/playbutton.png" width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: debido a que la maquetacíon del proyecto no la hice yo, si no me la entregaron así no sé porqué no me centraba con tu forma, pero gracias a tu ayuda complementé para terminar el centrado, ya me funciona, perfecto muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el posicionamiento relativo y absoluto para superponer las imágenes.

He optado por centrar la imagen con respecto al div relativo. El estilo "display: inline-block" evita que el control no ocupe todo el ancho (como ocurriría si su display tomara el valor "block"), sino solo el que necesite para contener a sus hijos.

Después centramos la imagen usando la más que conocida técnica que usa top, left y transform. Recomiendo la lectura de https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ para conocer en profundidad todas las técnicas.

Sí, el gato es el supuesto icono a centrar.

```html
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; position:relative">
        <img src="https://process.filestackapi.com/AhTgLagciQByzXpFGRI0Az/resize=width:250,height:200,fit:scale/http://areametropolitana.softwareestrategico.com/PublishingImages/Paginas/Forms/AllItems/Nairo.jpeg" width="268" hspace="16" height="268" vspace="16" />
        <div style="display: inline-block; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)">
            <img border="0" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Un saludo

Comment: gracias por el concejo, leeré tú documentación, ya lo pude realizar gracias al del primer comentario, agradezco el compromiso